# Adding 1 day to NOW() in php

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, timestamp

I'm trying to add 1 day to the current time in my sql database using a php script and then store this value back into the database. To do this I am doing the following, however the $newdate variable doesn't get stored when I attempt to use a mysqli query to store it in my database.

```
$time = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT NOW() FROM cities");
$curr_time = mysqli_fetch_array($time);
$curr_date = $curr_time['NOW()'];
$newdate = strtotime ( '+1 day' , strtotime ( $curr_date) ) ;
$newdate = date ( 'Y-m-j' , $newdate );
```

Comment: `select curdate() + interval 1 day AS datealias`, then` `$curr_time['datealias']`. if you only want today's date, then DON'T select from a table. you'd get a result set with as many "today" dates as you have records in the table. a major waste of cpu/network/disk bandwidth. plus doing `mysqldate->strtotime->strtotime->date` is a waste as well. you can use `date_format()` directly in mysql and bypassd the multiple string/timestamp conversions you're forcing.

Comment: Huh? `"SELECT NOW() FROM cities"` makes no sense!?! **1** Why go to the database and **2** Why use a table name when `"SELECT NOW()"` would do?

Comment: Which is your datetime column in your database? You don't need to do all that...

Comment: Is curdate going to return the same value as the NOW() function in SQL? I'm storing this on an online server so I'm not sure if the timezone etc would effect the values returned by curdate and NOW() and if they would be the same..

Comment: PS: You have not written any code to store anything back to the database? Making less and less sense here

Comment: @RiggsFolly I haven't posted that code because it's a simple INSERT INTO query, I know it works fine with all the other values in the table, I just posted what is relevant to the issue

Comment: @mankee If you want to `SELECT` to `INSERT` later, just use `INSERT INTO table (datecol) VALUES NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY`. No need to do this PHP dance at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do the INSERT, you dont need 2 round trips to the database

```
INSERT INTO table (c1,c2,somedate) VALUES (1,2, CURDATE() + interval 1 day)
```

Comment: This is my query and for some reason it doesn't work. :   $result = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO images (image_id, user_id, image, longitude, latitude, city, delete_at) VALUES ('$uuid','$user','$image','$longitude','$latitude','$curr_city', CURDATE() + interval 1 day)");

Comment: It works when I run it in phpmyadmin however it doesn't work from the php script

Comment: nevermind, my mistake, I forgot to empty the table from the previous test data so there was a conflict of primary keys